# HTML White space between image and scrollbar in a <ul>

Tags: html, css, image, scroll, whitespace

firstly I am including an image for clarity sake

[image]

It is the white space in between the scrollbar and the images that I am trying to eliminate. My reason for this is that I want to have three scrolling unordered lists in-line with eachother, as shown in the code.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <style media="screen" type="text/css">

nav ul
   {
     height:500px; width:43%;
     overflow:hidden; 
     overflow-y:scroll; 
     overflow-x:scroll;
     display: inline-block;
     padding: 5px;
   }


ul
{
float:left;
margin:0 5px;
list-style-type: none;
}

img
{
  width = 100%;
}
body
   {
     margin = 0;
   }

</style>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <header>header area</header>

<nav>
    <ul>
      <li><img src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/pic_mountain.jpg"></li>
      <li><img src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/pic_mountain.jpg"></li> 
      <li><img src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/pic_mountain.jpg"></li> 
      <li><img src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/pic_mountain.jpg"></li>
      <li><img src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/pic_mountain.jpg"></li>
      <li><img src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/pic_mountain.jpg"></li>
      <li><img src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/pic_mountain.jpg"></li> 
      <li><img src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/pic_mountain.jpg"></li> 
      <li><img src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/pic_mountain.jpg"></li>
      <li><img src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/pic_mountain.jpg"></li>

  </ul>
  <ul>
      <li><img src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/pic_mountain.jpg"></li>
      <li><img src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/pic_mountain.jpg"></li> 
      <li><img src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/pic_mountain.jpg"></li> 
      <li><img src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/pic_mountain.jpg"></li>
      <li><img src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/pic_mountain.jpg"></li>
      <li><img src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/pic_mountain.jpg"></li>
      <li><img src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/pic_mountain.jpg"></li> 
      <li><img src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/pic_mountain.jpg"></li> 
      <li><img src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/pic_mountain.jpg"></li>
      <li><img src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/pic_mountain.jpg"></li>

  </ul>

   <ul>
      <li><img src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/pic_mountain.jpg"></li>
      <li><img src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/pic_mountain.jpg"></li> 
      <li><img src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/pic_mountain.jpg"></li> 
      <li><img src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/pic_mountain.jpg"></li>
      <li><img src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/pic_mountain.jpg"></li>
      <li><img src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/pic_mountain.jpg"></li>
      <li><img src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/pic_mountain.jpg"></li> 
      <li><img src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/pic_mountain.jpg"></li> 
      <li><img src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/pic_mountain.jpg"></li>
      <li><img src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/pic_mountain.jpg"></li>

  </ul>
  </nav>

  <footer>footer area</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Problem

`img` is an inline element, so set it as `display:block` (or `vertical-align:bottom` given it is by default `vertical-align:baseline`)

#### Notes

- you have 2 typos:

`body{margin=0}` and `img{width=100%}`, should be with `:`

- added code to make your lists alongside with each other

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box
}
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.cf:before,
.cf:after {
    content: " "; 
    display: table; 
}

.cf:after {
    clear: both;
}
nav ul {
  height: 500px;
  width: calc((100% / 3) - 10px);
  overflow: hidden;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px;
}
ul {
  float: left;
  margin: 0 5px;
  list-style-type: none;
}
img {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid red
}
```

```html
<header>header area</header>

<nav class="cf">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/pic_mountain.jpg">
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/pic_mountain.jpg">
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/pic_mountain.jpg">
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/pic_mountain.jpg">
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/pic_mountain.jpg">
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/pic_mountain.jpg">
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/pic_mountain.jpg">
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/pic_mountain.jpg">
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/pic_mountain.jpg">
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/pic_mountain.jpg">
    </li>

  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/pic_mountain.jpg">
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/pic_mountain.jpg">
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/pic_mountain.jpg">
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/pic_mountain.jpg">
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/pic_mountain.jpg">
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/pic_mountain.jpg">
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/pic_mountain.jpg">
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/pic_mountain.jpg">
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/pic_mountain.jpg">
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/pic_mountain.jpg">
    </li>

  </ul>

  <ul>
    <li>
      <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/pic_mountain.jpg">
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/pic_mountain.jpg">
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/pic_mountain.jpg">
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/pic_mountain.jpg">
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/pic_mountain.jpg">
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/pic_mountain.jpg">
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/pic_mountain.jpg">
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/pic_mountain.jpg">
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/pic_mountain.jpg">
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/pic_mountain.jpg">
    </li>

  </ul>
</nav>

<footer>footer area</footer>
```

Comment: Thank you very much that is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/yjj628g4/

Is that what you are trying to accomplish?

If so, it is just a width issue on the "ul"

The width you have here is widening the area around the images.

```
nav ul
   {
    height:500px; **width:43%**;
    overflow:hidden;
    overflow-y:scroll;
    overflow-x:scroll;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 5px;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

For 3 lists alongside each other the `width` should *not*  be 43% (like in your code), but 33%, plus you should add `box-sizing: border-box;` to include the padding in the width. Also, `overflow: hidden` makes no sense in combination with `overflow-x: scroll`  and `overflow-y: scroll` - just replace all that with `overflow: scroll`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you just need to adjust your styles. You had a few incorrect selectors `img {width = 100%;}` should be `{width: 100%;}` and I adjusted your styles to make the images and columns responsive to the browser width.

```
nav ul {height:500px; width:31%; overflow:hidden; overflow-y:scroll; overflow-x:scroll; display: inline-block; padding: 0;}
ul {float:left; margin: 0 2% 0 0; list-style-type: none;}
img {width: 100%;}
body {margin: 0;}
```

That should fix everything. The scroll bar will expand to the far right of it's container by default, so you need to ensure that your container doesn't expand beyond it's content.